# NPM warning required peer dependency is not installed when installing rallycoding dependency

Tags: react-native, config, atom-editor, eslint

I am getting an error when installing the `rallycoding` dependency. The following warning occurs:

> Required peer dependency is not installed

The whole erro is like *"install peer dependencies yourself"*.

```
npm WARN eslint-config-standard@14.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-promise@>=4.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-standard@14.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-standard@>=4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@2.2.3 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || 3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@1.16.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "albums",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-rallycoding": "^1.2.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried every thing....chache delete +module file delete and again install + install peers etc ...but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:
`npm i eslint@^5.0.0`
It works for me

Comment: thanks ....... whent i tried to install it in gitbash rather than in cmd ...it worked for me